# How do I post to MYSQL database with jquery ajax post method?

Tags: php, jquery

I know how to do a normal PHP post, but with a PHP post you specify the $conn variable which has the IP address and the login info to the database. However with jquery ajax post method I am not exactly certain how to post to the database.

```
$.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )
```

This is the syntax for the post method. What am I missing here?

Comment: what is `normal PHP post`?

Comment: the `url` is the php file location. ie if youre sending the ajax file to `paymentvalidation.php`, then your ajax url will be `url: paymentvalidation.php`

Comment: you cannot post from javascript, you have to post to a PHP script and from the script post to the database. Anyway, this is not a question for stackoverflow.

Comment: @AlexAngelico Logged

Answer (score 0):

`$.post` is a function for making HTTP POST requests.

MySQL is not an HTTP server. It can't handle HTTP requests.

There is no way to communicate directly with MySQL from JavaScript running in a web browser.

An HTTP server can pass a POST request (which can be triggered by `$.post`) to a server-side program (which can be written in any programming language you like, including PHP).

The PHP program can then read the data from the HTTP request (using the `$_POST` superglobal) and use that to insert data into the database (with either the PDO or `mysqli_*` APIs).